# Add a ViewStub programmatically to an RelativeLayout, than add a second ViewStub below the first

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams, viewstub

Hey I will shortly describe what I do in the code below:
I create an ViewStub (Vs) and add it to the RelativeLayout (Rl).
Then I want to add a new Vs to the same RL, so I create the stub2 and add it to rl. 
Then I reference to the Rl (which is inflatet) of the first and of the second Vs (rlInf1 ,rlInf2)
And then I set the Rl.Layoutparams so that the rlInf2 should be below the rlInf1 but they are overlapping.
How can I set the LayoutParams so that the new ViewStub is below the old one?
Any Ideas?

(I did not add the ViewStub in XML, but in Java-Code)

```
//Löschen des Standard-Tv
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoContentInfo);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_ContentInfo);
            rl.removeView(tv);
            //Erstellen eines ViewStubs
            ViewStub stub1 = new ViewStub(this);
            //zum richtigen Layout hinzufügen
            rl.addView(stub1);
            stub1.setLayoutResource(R.layout.routen_navi_infocontent);
            //Referenz zum eingefügten Layout herstellen
            View inflated = stub1.inflate();
            //Zugriff auf Inhalt des zufor referenzierten Layouts
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) inflated.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderInfocontent);
            myTextView.setText("hey");
            stub1.setId(View.generateViewId());
            stub1.setInflatedId(stub1.getId());
            RelativeLayout rlInf1 = (RelativeLayout) inflated.findViewById(R.id.Layout_infocontent);

            ViewStub stub2 = new ViewStub(this);
            //zum richtigen Layout hinzufügen
            rl.addView(stub2);
            stub2.setLayoutResource(R.layout.routen_navi_infocontent);
            //Referenz zum eingefügten Layout herstellen
            View inflated2 = stub2.inflate();
            RelativeLayout rlInf2 = (RelativeLayout) inflated2.findViewById(R.id.Layout_infocontent);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,rlInf1.getId());
            rlInf2.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: what do you need those `ViewStub`s for, if you are inflating them right away?

Comment: I just test it...I want a dynamic side -> Maybe I need the first time 2Vs and at the second time I need it 3 times...

And before I am getting started with the real programm I want to test if I can position a Vs below another @pskink

Comment: BTW `LinearLayout`s are not good enough? or why not using `RecyclerView` instead?

Comment: What is the RecyclerView? Maybe there is another possibility to do what I want...I have an Rl which I have to "include" on runtime and sometimes I have to include the same Rl two or more times below the previous one

Comment: So first read about ListView, then about RecyclerView

Comment: can i add a Layout without ViewStubs? @pskink

Comment: you can add any `View` without `ViewStub`, just call `ViewGroup#addView`, but really read about the list  containers like `ListViw` and / or `RecyclerView`

Comment: thank you, I read about ListView and found sth that helped @pskink

Answer (score 1):

Once you inflate the view into the `ViewStub`, the `ViewStub` is gone, so it is useless to change the id on it. You need to change it on the inflated view.
So change

`stub1.setId(View.generateViewId());`

to

`inflated.setId(View.generateViewId());`

And change the last two lines to:

```
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,inflated.getId());
    inflated2.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Also, you might want to grab the existing `LayoutParams` from the `inflated` view and not create new ones, otherwise you will end up overwriting all the existing ones.

BTW: I have to assume that the addition of the `ViewStubs` and immediate inflation is just a test for something and not the real flow, right? :-)

ADDITION:
Yes, you can add layouts without using `ViewStub`

```
    View inflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.routen_navi_infocontent, rl, false);
    inflated.setId(View.generateViewId());
    rl.addView(inflated);

    View inflated2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.routen_navi_infocontent, rl, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,inflated.getId());
    inflated2.setLayoutParams(p);
    rl.addView(inflated2);

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) inflated.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderInfocontent);
    myTextView.setText("hey");
```

Comment: thank you, I found another whay to do it (with lists) but my problem is that the list only shows the first Item and not the second...so if I am not able to do it with lists i will test your code

Comment: Ohhh it was just a fail:D It shows both elements but I have to scroll...I thought that the relative layout will expand if the list is too long...@N.T.